# How to get records for a column having a value but not other

Tags: sql

I have a dataset as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM all_trans LIMIT 6

+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+----------+
| transaction_id|card_event_id|card_pos_id|card_point_country|transaction_label|module_name| post_date|
+---------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+-----------------+-----------+----------+
|0P2117055584563|   2480330365|   E3KB2938|                CZ|       FUN0402007|      regex|2022-01-17|
|0P2117055584563|   2480330365|   E3KB2938|                CZ|            FUN04|        mcc|2022-01-17|
|0P2117057388514|   2480338194|   E3KB2938|                CZ|       FUN0402007|      regex|2022-01-17|
|0P2117057388514|   2480338194|   E3KB2938|                CZ|            FUN04|        mcc|2022-01-17|
|0P2117058209585|   2480339519|   E3KB2938|                CZ|       FUN0402007|      regex|2022-01-17|
|0P2117058209585|   2480339519|   E3KB2938|                CZ|            FUN04|        mcc|2022-01-17|
```

I want to get the transactions with no `'regex'` value in `module_name` (either with `'mcc'` value or none whatsoever).

I tried:

```
SELECT a.transaction_id
FROM all_trans a
    JOIN all_trans b ON a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
WHERE a.module_name='mcc' AND b.module_name<>'regex'
LIMIT 100
```

But still getting transactions with both mcc and regex values in the column module_name.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: What output do you want to get from the provided sample dataset?

Comment: Check for the `exists/not exists` clause

Comment: Can you share the current output and the expected output?

Comment: Is `SELECT transaction_id FROM all_trans where module_name <> 'regex'` just too simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, and use a `case` *expression* in the `HAVING` clause to make sure there is no regex value.

```
SELECT transaction_id
FROM all_trans
GROUP BY transaction_id
HAVING COUNT(case when module_name = 'regex' then 1 end) = 0
LIMIT 100
```

Will return *distinct* transaction_id's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` statement with condition like:

```
SELECT a.transaction_id
FROM all_trans a
LEFT JOIN all_trans b ON 
    a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id AND b.module_name = 'regex'
WHERE a.module_name='mcc' AND b.transaction_id IS NULL
LIMIT 100
```

`WHERE ... b.transaction_id IS NULL` remove from list transactions that have 'regex'

Another option as mentioned by @Egrest Basha is using `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT a.transaction_id
FROM all_trans a
WHERE a.module_name='mcc' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM all_trans b WHERE a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id AND b.module_name = 'regex'
)
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I'd _guess_ OP wants distinct transaction id's.